# Saving a HTML path to a file

Tags: c#, filestream

Edited my code to use WebClient...still doesnt work

```
string hhtmlurl = /Thumbnail.aspx?productID=23&Firstname=jimmy&lastnight=smith;

string strFileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}", hfUserID.Value, Request.QueryString["pid"].ToString() + documentID.ToString());
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile("http://www.url.ca/" + hhtmlurl.Value + "card=1", strFileName);
```

Comment: How doesn't it work? What *does* it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method. This will give you string return for the entire html content. Write this string in whatever file you want

```
public string GetHtmlPageContent(string url)
    {
        HttpWebResponse siteResponse = null;
        HttpWebRequest siteRequest = null;
        string content= string.Empty;

        try
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(url);
            siteRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            siteResponse = (HttpWebResponse)siteRequest.GetResponse();

            content = GetResponseText(siteResponse);
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            // Log error
        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {
            // Log error
        }

        return content;
    }

        public string GetResponseText(HttpWebResponse response)
    {
        string responseText = string.Empty;

        if (response == null)
            return string.Empty;

        try
        {
            StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            responseText = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            responseReader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log error
        }

        return responseText;
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Where in this code do I save the file and put in my own file name?

Comment: That part is not available here. That you have to implement. So you will call my above method and it will return you entire webpage content in string. Then use streamwriter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w.aspx) to write this string into another file

Answer (score 0):

[`WebClient.DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx) would probably be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of FileStream, use the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class, which offers the delightfully simple `DownloadFile()` method:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Downloadfile("http://www.url.ca/" + hhtmlurl + "card=1", strFileName);
```

Comment: Ummm...it doesnt appear to be working....I have noticed that my client.Downloadfile is not greenish like yours..its black I am using System.net, am I missing something?

Comment: Make sure you have a `using System.Net;` directive in your code, or explicitly call `System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient()`

Comment: Also, please don't edit your questions like that. It makes the answers meaningless, and doesn't help future readers who may stumble into this page.

Comment: Opps, sorry about that...No erros when I build the solution...could it be something I am using that could effect it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7601/discussion-between-user1193385-and-avner-shahar-kashtan)